# How to set a custom title on time picker?

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

I'm making a date picker with a title but the view its ugly because there is no margin bottom, how can i make a margin to make it little pretty?[image: timepickerdialog screenshot]

As you can see it's very ugly.

My code:

```
if(endTime.isEmpty() || startTime.isEmpty()){

    int CustomHour       = 12;
    int CustomMinute     = 00;
    int hour             = CustomHour;
    int minute           = CustomMinute;

    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(ActivityAlarm.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
    {       

        int callCount = 0;   //To track number of calls to onTimeSet()              
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) 
        {   

...

    }, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ActivityAlarm.this));
    tpd.setTitle("Set Time");           
    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return  tpd;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

In code do this:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, null);
        TextView texts=(TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textss);
        texts.setText("Start Time");
        tpd.setCustomTitle(dialogView);
```

In xml make a file named:

**text_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: i'm not using any xml file

Comment: then post your code snippet, it will be easier to modify your code according to requirement

Comment: i do that and the app crashes when i try to open the TimePicker, also get an error on "getLayoutInflater" it says "The method getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: if you are using fragment then do this: getActivity().getLayoutInflater();   Also not that, add my code before return tpd;

Comment: sorry i had to change this: LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ActivityAlarm.this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86840/discussion-between-aakash-and-portal47).